# Show the Name of person and pid who Issues Maximum number of warning

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to write a query who issues a maximum number of warnings. Should display name and pid of a person.

Table required are
Person with  pid  and person_name attributes
Issues with pid and wwid attributes
Warning with wwid attribute attributes

I wrote the following query and it didn't work

```
select distinct p.name, Count (p.pid)times 
  from person p,
       Issues I,
       Warnings w
 where p.pid=w.pid 
   and i.pid =p.pid;
```

Comment: what did you expect exactly? And what was the result contrary to your expectation?

Comment: Define "didn't work".  Potentially, the query you provided would show each user and the number of warnings they issued.  Does it do that successfully?  If so, then you'd just need to get the row from that query with the largest count.

Comment: may be add "group by p.name" at the end and remove distinct

Comment: @JustinCave No, I don't think his query will return any sort of per person metric because `COUNT` is an aggregate function and `GROUP BY` is not being used.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something more meaningful. The title should describe the problem you're having or the question you're asking in a way that will be useful to a future reader here who sees it in a search result. The tags you used indicate *database* and *SQL*, so they're of no value in the title, which leaves the single word *query*. Having dozens of questions titled *query* or *Database SQL query* would be absolutely useless. While you're making that [edit], you can explain specifically what *didn't work* means - in what way didn't it work?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really stop using those ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the `where`. Learn to use the `JOIN` operator

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT p.name,
       COUNT(*) AS times
FROM person p
INNER JOIN Issues i
    ON p.pid = i.pid
INNER JOIN Warnings w
    ON p.pid = w.pid 
GROUP BY p.pid
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi,
 Try this query,

```
SELECT P.name,MAX(P.pid) FROM
Person P
INNER JOIN Issues I
ON (I.PID = P.PID)
INNER JOIN Warnings W
ON (W.PID = P.PID)
GROUP BY P.name
ORDER BY P.name
```

Hope this is what you need. If not post your source data

Comment: its not (max>num) num max(pid) of a peroson who has issued the most warning

Comment: Provide how your data looks and how should your result look like